I don't understand the reason behind O(h) time complexity in this MIT OCW Algorithms question
I faced the following question in a problem session: Gal Ore is a scientist who studies climate. As part of her research, she often needs to query the maximum temperature the earth has observed within a particular date range in history, based on a growing set of measurements which she collects and adds to frequently. Assume that temperatures and dates are integers representing values at some consistent resolution. Help Gal evaluate such range queries efficiently by implementing a database supporting the following operations.
record_temp(t, d)
max_in_range $(d 1, d 2)$ record a measurement of temperature $t$ on date $d$ return max temperature observed between dates $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ inclusive
To solve this problem, we will store temperature measurements in an AVL tree with binary search tree semantics keyed by date, where each node A stores a measurement A.item with a date property A. item.key and temperature property A. item.temp.
(a) To help evaluate the desired range query, we will augment each node with:
A.max_t temp, the maximum temperature stored in A's subtree; and both A.min_ date and A.max_date, the minimum and maximum dates stored in A's subtree respectively. Describe a $O(1)$-time algorithm to compute the value of these augmentations on node A, assuming all other nodes in A's subtree have already been correctly augmented.
(b) A subtree partially overlaps an inclusive date range if the subtree contains at least one measurement that is within the range and at least one measurement that is outside the range. Given an inclusive date range, prove that for any binary search tree containing measurements keyed by dates, there is at most one node in the tree whose left and right subtrees both partially overlap the range.
(c) Let subtree_max_in_range ( $A, d 1, d 2$ ) be the maximum temperature of any measurement stored in node A's subtree with a date between $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ inclusive (returning None if no measurements exist in the range). Assuming the tree has been augmented as in part (a), describe a recursive algorithm to compute the value of subtree_max_in_range(A, d1, d2). If $h$ is the height of A's subtree, your algorithm should run in $O(h)$ time when A partially overlaps the range, and in $O(1)$ time otherwise.
For the solution they gave for part (c), I don't understand the following:(Please note that case 3 is the following: partially overlaps the range.) Lastly, in case (3), recursively compute the max temperature in range for each of $A$'s child subtrees and return the max between them and the temperature at $A$ (since the temperature at $A$ must be in range). This algorithm takes at most $O(h)$ time. To see this, observe that the claim in part (b) ensures that in all but one case (3) node, a recursive call in at least one of its child subtrees will take $O(1)$ time. So the shape of the recursive calls will be the union of at most two paths from the root to another node in the tree, touching at most $O(h)$ nodes along the way, doing at most $O(1)$ work at each.
What I don't understand: Shouldn't the worst-case time complexity be $O(n)$ instead of $O(h)$? I mean we are traversing through all the nodes by recursively calling the function on the left and right subtrees. I don't understand how they are making use of the property in part (b) to prove that the worst-case time complexity is $O(h)$.
